# ios invalid_request while calling for autherization token using oauth

Tags: oauth, ios6

I'm using google api to do google lattitude operations in my application. I have done till autherizing the user using credentials. Now i'm trying to generate accesstoken using the autherization_code generated from the initial request. But it is throughing invalid_request as error in the didReceiveData function. can some one of you please suggest me to solve my problem. Oauth request format is suppose to be like follows.

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/v6xr77ewYqhvHSyW6UJ1w7jKwAzu&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

my ios code to perform the above service calll is follows

```
   NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=%@&client_id=363756608022.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=dury2bxloSVQ1sdJjg9MKO9s&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code",[userDefaults valueForKey:@"accessTokenResponse"]];    
     NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSLog(@"sendng req : %@",request);
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
```

Answer (score 0):

use asihttpheader to form header request. `[request setpostvalue" forkey :].` this solved my problem